# Export simple excel data into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel

My client got a excel file with the following structure

```
name     |     email
----------------------------
Name     |   email here
Name     |   email here
Name     |   email here
Name     |   email here
Name     |   email here
Name     |   email here
```

I would likes to make a MySQL database table according to this pattern and save the data into MySQL.

I am wonder how to do this. 
Also there is an option needed

We have to check that if that corresponding user had a correct email address, ie of the form @ .

Can we check the data as a loop while importing ?

Also how to convert this data to MySQL ?

Comment: Is it feasible to convert to CSV first?

Comment: As @Asad said before, first convert to CSV and then use mysql to import the file into the database.

Comment: as @Asad, i would definetly save excel sheet as csv first, then parse and validate it with PHP and make one multi-insert query from it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Save this excel file as csv and run the following code with add your changings

```
$source = fopen('email.csv', 'r') or die("Problem open file");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($source, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $name = $data[0];
        $email = $data[1];


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`name`,`email`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$email."') ");


    }
    fclose($source);
```

Comment: With this code, I am able to get only the first row of the file.

Comment: This code is open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

There is a 
Iibrary named PHPExcel. With this library you can easily parse any excel file.  Or you can export your file as csv and will be easier for you. php has native functions to handle csv files.  You can use `fgetcsv()` or `str_getcsv()`.

Answer (score 2):

Goto this link and download the php class that will read the excel file and return the array. This array will hold the all data written in excel file.

[php excel reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)

Its free...

You can also see the demo there.

I am already using it. Its definitely good.

Any other help on this you can freely ask to me.

Comment: is there any file size limitation ?

Comment: Except the limitation of PHP memory

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
                            <tr>
                            <td><h5><b>Select Standared</b></h5></td>
                            <td><select name="chap_sel_std" id="chap_sel_std">
                                                        <option>Select Standared</option>
                                                <?php
                                                    $exe_sel_std = mysql_query("SELECT * from s_standared");
                                                    while($r_sel_std = mysql_fetch_array($exe_sel_std)){
                                                        $sel_stdid = $r_sel_std['std_id'];
                                                        $sel_std = $r_sel_std['std'];?>

                                                        <option value="<?php echo $sel_stdid; ?>"><?php echo $sel_std;?></option>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                </select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5><b>Select Font</b></h5></td>
                                <td><select name="sel_f_gn_que">
                                    <option>Select Font</option>
                                        <?php
                                            $xf = mysql_query("SELECT * from s_font");
                                            while($rquef = mysql_fetch_array($xf)){
                                                $f_id = $rquef['f_id'];
                                                $f_name = $rquef['f_name'];  ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $f_id; ?>"><?php echo $f_name; }?>  </option>
                                </select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5><b>Upload Question<h5><b></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="btn">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-green big" name="add_que" value="Add Questions"></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="saveandexit" class="" value="Finish" onclick="close();"></td>
                            </tr>
                    </form>
                    </table>
                    </div>                   

    <?php

            $data = array();

    //$db =& DB::connect("mysql://root@localhost/names", array());
    //if (PEAR::isError($db)) { die($db->getMessage()); }
      //quetype    difficulty    standard    subject    chap    que    marks

    function add_person($quetype,$dif, $subject,$chap_name,$que,$marks)
    {
     global $data, $db;

     //$sth = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO names VALUES( 0, ?, ?, ?, ? )" );
    // $db->execute( $sth, array( $first, $middle, $last, $email ) );

     $data []= array(
       'quetype' => $quetype, 
       'difficulty' => $dif,
       'subject' => $subject,
       'chap' => $chap_name,
       'que' => $que,
       //'ans' => $ans,
       'marks' => $marks

     );
    }

    if(!isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
        echo "";
    }elseif($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
    {
     $dom = DOMDocument::load( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
     $rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'Row' );
     $first_row = true;
     foreach ($rows as $row)
     {
       if ( !$first_row )
       {
         $quetype = "";
         $dif = "";
         $subject = "";
         $chap_name = "";
         $que = "";
         //$ans = "";
         $marks = "";

         $index = 1;
         $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName( 'Cell' );
         foreach( $cells as $cell )
         {
           $ind = $cell->getAttribute( 'Index' );
           if ( $ind != null ) $index = $ind;

           if ( $index == 1 ) $quetype = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 2 ) $dif = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 4 ) $subject = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 6 ) $chap_name = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 8) $que = $cell->nodeValue;
           //if ( $index == 9) $ans = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 9) $marks = $cell->nodeValue;

           $index += 1;
         }
         add_person($quetype,$dif, $subject,$chap_name,$que,$marks);

         if(isset($_POST['add_que'])){    

                 $chap_sel_std = $_POST['chap_sel_std'];
                 echo $simquefnt = $_POST['sel_f_gn_que'];

                    //que_id    quetype_id    chap_id    sub_id    std_id    que    dif_id    marks    que_cdate
             //$chap_sel_std = $_POST['chap_sel_std']; //que_id    quetype_id    chap_id    sub_id    std_id    que    dif_id    marks    que_cdate
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
                          s_question
                          VALUES (null,'$quetype','$chap_name','$subject','$chap_sel_std','$que','NO IMAGE','$dif','$marks','$simquefnt','$current')");                                                        
    //         header("location:../admin/quetionaris.php#tabs-que"); 
         echo "Successfully Added";
          }
       }
       $first_row = false;
     }
    }
    ?>
```