# Get Raw or Colum from CSV with PHP

Tags: php, csv, calculated-columns

I am searching for a PHP Code to get a Row/Column from a CSV with the help of PHP.
what is important:

I want to add the number of the Row/Column in the code to get the Name of it!

```
ISO_COUNTRY_CODE,CNT_POSTAL_CODE,ORDER1_ADMIN_TYP_1112,ORDER2_ADMIN_TYP_1113,ORDER8_ADMIN_TYP_1119,BUILTUP_ID
AND,7,0,0,7,41
ARG,1970,25,0,514,4076
AUS,2612,9,0,10978,4597
AUT,2213,9,95,2354,10304
BEL,1148,3,11,589,3781
BGR,4507,28,0,264,5375
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231547/export-simple-excel-data-into-mysql-using-php/13231633#13231633)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

For more information you can see : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php